# Android studio javacv fail on writting image using imwrite

Tags: android, javacv

Currently i am trying to play with image processing in Android studio using javacv. i have add these five code in dependency:

```
compile 'org.bytedeco:javacv:+'
compile 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv:3.0.0-1.1:android-x86'
compile 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:ffmpeg:2.8.1-1.1:android-x86'
compile 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv:3.0.0-1.1:android-arm'
compile 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:ffmpeg:2.8.1-1.1:android-arm'
```

I have found that the systax is totally different from the one in Eclipse.
For example:

```
opencv_core.Mat img = imread( dir + "mountain.jpg");
opencv_core.Mat temp = new opencv_core.Mat(img.rows() , img.cols());
opencv_core.flip(img, temp, 1);
imwrite(dir + "123.jpg", temp );
```

However nothing is written in my dir.
Anyone know how to write it in my specified dir.
Please give me a helping hand

Comment: what is **dir** path here ?

Comment: String dir = "C:/Users/Leo/Documents/GitHub/myapp";

Comment: path, does not seems like path of internal/external storage of device. it should be Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()